# Keep files number by deleting old files?

Tags: bash, git

I want to keep my files based on the date it was modified from GitHub not the local file when i clone my repo... I am bit stuck how to do that at the moment, any help would be appreciated..

```
#!/bin/bash
LIMIT=30
NO=0
NUMBER=$(find logs/ -name "*.json" |wc -l)
if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]  #if number greater than limit
 then
    del=$(($NUMBER-$LIMIT))
   if [ "$del" -lt "$NO" ]
    then
     del=$(($del*-1))
   fi
   echo $del
   FILES=$(ls -dt logs/*.json| tail -n "$del" | xargs rm)
  git rm -f "${FILES[@]}"
  #delete the originals
  git commit -m "Deleting old files"
 fi
```

Comment: This is terrifying to me. You want to delete files from a git repo because they are older than a month? What in the world are you using the repo for? Not saying it's a automatically a bad idea, it's just really scary from the perspective of someone turning your code loose on a code repo...

Comment: Note that every Git commit that remains "live" in history holds every file forever. Deleting a file and making a new commit doesn't save any space. It does de-clutter your working tree, of course—but log files in general don't seem like they should be stored in Git in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
git log --name-only --pretty=format: --since="1 month ago" --until="1 day ago"
```

to get the list of files that were modified in the last month.
You can use

```bash
git log --name-only --pretty=format: --since="1 month ago" --until="1 day ago" | xargs rm
```

to remove them.
You can use

```bash
git commit -m "Deleting old files"
```

to commit the changes.

You can use

```bash
git log --name-only --pretty=format: --since="1 month ago" --until="1 day ago" | xargs rm && git commit -m "Deleting old files"
```

to do all of the above in one command.